# Graph Data Modeling - Node vs Relationship Neo4j Comment Nodes

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

What is the most effective/scalable way to model data in Neo4j. Say for example you are making a hypothetical movie review site. Requirements are:

1. Users can be friends with other users.
2. Users can join groups
3. Users can watch a movie.
4. Users can recommend their friends/groups movies.
5. Users can comment on a movie they watched

   MERGE (c:User{name:"Chandler"})
   MERGE (j:User{name:"Joey"})
   MERGE (c)-[:FRIENDS {Since:1994}]-(j)
   MERGE (c)-[:MEMBER {Since:1994}]-(g:Group{name:"CoffeeClub"})
   MERGE (j)-[:MEMBER {Since:1995}]-(g)

   MATCH (c:User{name:"Chandler"})
   MERGE (c)-[:WATCHED]-(m:Movie {name:"PulpFiction"})
   MERGE (c)-[:WATCHED]-(m:Movie {name:"DumbnDumber"})

[image]
What is the most effective/scaleable way of implementing Req #4 & #5 ?

Use Case 1:
"Chandler" wants to recommend "DumbnDumber" To "Joey" and also comment: "Could this movie beee any more ridiculous"

Use Case 2:"
"Joey" wants to recommend "PulpFiction" To "CoffeeClub" and also comment:"How you Doin'?"

Comment: This is a broad question that might not be a good fit for Stack Overflow; in general, you should post what you've done, a problem you're having, and a specific question, then people can help.  Looks like you want general advice on how to build a recommender system and do data modeling.  There are a lot of good links out there that you should read to get that information (I'll provide one).  Try something out, then please ask a more specific question.  http://linkurio.us/using-neo4j-to-build-a-recommendation-engine-based-on-collaborative-filtering/

Comment: Hi @FrobberOfBits I do have a board statement in my question "What is the most effective/scalable way to model data in Neo4j." However towards the end I am very specific in terms on my problem and my use case. Thanks for the link though good read :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for #4

I would probably create a recommendation node that is linked to the user, the movie and the group or friend node.

for #5

- you could put the comment as a property in the :WATCHED relationship
- you could create an additional :COMMENTED relationships between user and movie
- you could create an additional comment node between user and movie

It all depends on how you want to use those comments later, if there should be comment threads etc.